# JavaC not initializing when "Open Command Window Here"

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, command-line, javac

When I try to *shift*+right-click a folder window, and click on: `Open command window here`, it brings up a command window, already `cd`ed to the path, like normal. I do have JavaC installed, and working, from the command line using `javac`, however opening the cmd window from `Open command window here`, and typing `javac`, it says:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

but it normally shows the help, without `Open command window here`.

[image: This is the context menu with <code>Open command window here</code> by _shift_+right-clicking].

My `path` variable is: `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\------;C:\Program Files\Java;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\CCleaner;C:\Program Files\Java;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin`

The path to Java and JavaC are in the `path` variable.

[image: This is my cmd window, but it's not much because it doesn't show the full path because of the window size]

Maybe this will help?:

[image: Maybe this will help?]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188801/discussion-on-question-by-therealsuicune-javac-not-initializing-when-open-comma).

Comment: I would also, from the environment variables window, adjust your variables so that you don't have repeats too. From your provided list, you have two instances of `C:\Windows`, `C:\Program Files\Java`, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201`. Also, _this is not my area, but_, I don't expect to see locations like `C:\Program Files\Java`, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201` there either, just the two with the `\bin` directories, I thought they were usually attributed to `%JAVA_HOME%`, which I have noted you have not set!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure it's in the Path environment variable. Edit it (e.g., in Windows 10, go to Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables, choose Path and edit it) and make sure you have something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin` in it.

Comment: @TheRealSuicune, your question does not mentioned `PATH` at all, it's only mentioned in some comments; if it's relevant to the question, [edit] it and include the information there, so everything is in one place; also regard comments may be cleaned up in future...

Answer (score 1):

***Yes!*** I finally got it to work! You see the registry screenshot of the 'Open command window here' option, the **`command`** key's **`(Default)`** string is `cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"`, I removed the `/s` part, so it's `cmd.exe /k pushd "%V"`, then I restarted the PC.

Comment: The change you have reported should not make any difference whatsoever to whether `javac` is recognised. Even the following modifications, will not even change the behavior of opening the right clicked directories location, `cmd.exe /k pushd %V`, `cmd.exe /s /k pushd %V`, `cmd.exe /k pushd "%V"`, `cmd.exe /s /k pushd "%V"`, `cmd.exe /k "pushd "%V""` and cmd /s /k "pushd "%V"".

Comment: Maybe it was just the restart of my PC?

Comment: You can modify the registry data and the very next right click will use the new data so rebooting will not change anything. Therefore the answer you've marked as accepted is not a solution to your issue.

Comment: More like: It should of worked before but it didn't, but now it does.

Comment: Well that would be guesswork, as you had absolutely ruined your environment variables... Oh and whilst we're on that subject, you never provided feedback on why did you not have a `%JAVA_HOME%` variable?

Comment: I installed jdk, and jre. I recall back to installing jre, [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/win8.jsp). But I never knew about `%JAVA_HOME%`.